# Not able to resolve PUT and POST issue with spring boot

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am building an application with spring boot with REST my GET method is working but POST and PUT method is not working giving exception :

```
2015-05-28 16:30:09.498 DEBUG 22670 --- [qtp536775614-18] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /api/v1/user
2015-05-28 16:30:09.500 DEBUG 22670 --- [qtp536775614-18] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'PUT' not supported
2015-05-28 16:30:09.500 DEBUG 22670 --- [qtp536775614-18] .w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'PUT' not supported
2015-05-28 16:30:09.500 DEBUG 22670 --- [qtp536775614-18] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'PUT' not supported
2015-05-28 16:30:09.501  WARN 22670 --- [qtp536775614-18] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'PUT' not supported
2015-05-28 16:30:09.501 DEBUG 22670 --- [qtp536775614-18] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2015-05-28 16:30:09.502 DEBUG 22670 --- [qtp536775614-18] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

I searched a lot for this issue but not found satisfactorily solution.

My controller code is :

```
package com.samepinch.controllers;

import java.util.Map;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.samepinch.services.UserService;
import com.samepinch.utills.response.ResponseHandler;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class UserController {
    public static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    /**
     * to pass user info to service
     */
    /*@RequestMapping(value = "/signup",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Map<String, Object> saveUser(@RequestBody User user) {
successfully", HttpStatus.ACCEPTED, false, null);
    }*/

    /**
     * to delete user by id
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        userService.deleteUser(id);
    }

    /**
     * to update user by id
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public String updateUser() {
        System.out.println("in update method");
//      userService.updateUser(user);
        return "success";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Map<String,Object> getUsers(){
        log.info("getting user");
        return ResponseHandler.generateResponse("", HttpStatus.ACCEPTED, false, null);
    }

}       userService.saveUser(user);
        return ResponseHandler.generateResponse("User registerted successfully", HttpStatus.ACCEPTED, false, null);
    }*/

    /**
     * to delete user by id
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        userService.deleteUser(id);
    }

    /**
     * to update user by id
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public String updateUser() {
        System.out.println("in update method");
//      userService.updateUser(user);
        return "success";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Map<String,Object> getUsers(){
        log.info("getting user");
        return ResponseHandler.generateResponse("", HttpStatus.ACCEPTED, false, null);
    }

}
```

Comment: firstly change all the `value` to be unique.

Comment: Hi, i have removed all methods except update method  with PUT request but still it is not working

Comment: can you show us the code now that you have removed all but one of the PUT methods?

Comment: please clean up your example code, there's at least one orphan "*/" and a mismatched curly bracket too, not to speak of duplicate methods, don't make it difficult for us to help you